# How Do I debug this Segfault

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

Am I not allowed to delete a object ? Is that why it segfaults and can I use a self referential class as below or should I use it alternatively ?
advanced thanks

I actually trying to build a trie still the starting stage

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;
 #define NUMCHAR 26

typedef struct t_struct{
    bool iscomplete;
    t_struct * val[NUMCHAR];
};



class t_tree
{
private:
    bool iscomplete;
    t_tree * val[NUMCHAR];
public:
    t_tree* init(t_tree* node);
    void uninit(t_tree* node);
    t_tree* add_word(t_tree * node , const char* str);
    bool find_word(t_tree *node , const char* str);
};


t_tree* t_tree :: init(t_tree* node)
{
    cout << "Enter Initilized " << endl;
    if(node == NULL) node = new t_tree;
    node->iscomplete = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < NUMCHAR ; i++) node->val[i] = NULL;

    cout << "Node Initilized " << endl;
    return node;
}

void t_tree :: uninit(t_tree* node)
{
    cout << "Here  " <<node << endl;
    if(node == NULL) return;


    for(int i = 0 ; i < NUMCHAR ; i++) uninit(node->val[i]) ;

    cout << "Here deleted  " <<node << endl;
    delete node;
    cout << "Here deleted  " <<node << endl;
    node = NULL;
    cout << "Node Uninitilized " << endl;
}


t_tree* t_tree :: add_word (t_tree* node,const char* str)
{
    if (str[0] == '\0')  node->iscomplete = true;

    else{
    unsigned int ch = str[0] - 'a';
    if (node->val[ch] == NULL) node->val[ch] = init(node->val[ch]);
    str++;
    add_word(node->val[ch],str);
    }

return node;
}

int main()
{
    t_tree root;
    root.init(&root);
    root.uninit(&root);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `How Do I debug this Segfault` with a debugger?

Comment: Before you learn debugging (which you should learn) you need to learn C++ first, and how to handle classes and class instances (objects), because right now you treat objects and member functions more like it were C than C++, which leads to your problems. I suggest you check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and find a good tutorial there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental mistake with this is not understanding the difference between the heap and the stack.

Many languages only use a heap for objects like this, and deleting (or similar, such as Dispose()) can be called on them (however, even then, such languages typically use the `new` keyword to create such objects).

Here, you're trying to call `delete`, a heap operation, on an object allocated on the stack. This is not allowed at all.

This is such a fundamental concept in C++ its very important to learn it.

Comment: (I am mainly a C programmer) So what you are saying is new does not operate on malloc i.e allocate space from heap? I see from other sources that new allocates memory from "Free store". So when I use new  space is not actually allocated from Heap ...?

Comment: you didn't use new - you created the root object on the stack `t_tree root;` creates an object of type t_tree. if you had said `t_tree* root = new t_tree;` then you would have had an object on the heap that you could call `delete` on later (as you were doing).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to `delete` `t_tree* node` in `uninit()`, but your `t_tree* node` is actually `&root`, which is not a heap object, so you cant call `delete` on it.